# Why can't I add to a dictionary within my model from my controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, initialization, nsmutabledictionary

My model is intended to store JSON data.  Part of what's to be stored is an array nested in the JSON, which could be a varying number of elements.  This is how I retrieve that data in code.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SomeJsonFile" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *jsonFromFile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonFromFile options:0 error:&error];
DLog(@"simulated 'Stuff' JSON, stored in dictionary: %@", jsonData);
```

That works great.  A callback sends along that dictionary, at which point I experience my problem.  Here's an example of the nested array in the JSON.

```
        stuff =             (
                            {
                id = 11;
                "someState" = 1;
                someNumber = 100;
                description = "Human-readable text for thing #11!";
            },
                            {
                id = 22;
                "someState" = 0;
                someNumber = 20;
                description = "Human-readable text for thing #22!";
            },
                            {
                id = 33;
                "someState" = 1;
                someNumber = 250;
                description = "Human-readable text for thing #33!";
            },
        );
```

My model should store the data sent along there, but since that nested array is an unknown amount of elements, I've elected to:

1. Use an NSMutableArray to store the IDs of each array element.
2. Use an NSMutableDictionary for each property of the element (like someState, someNumber, description).
3. When the time comes to list all the elements of the model, I'll iterate through the array of IDs and use each ID as a key for each of the NSMutableDictionary properties, thus retrieving everything I need.

Those NSMutableDictionary properties from step 2 aren't responding.  They don't set the keys or values; they remain null.  From other questions, it seems this is because they aren't initialized.  Also from other questions, I've been able to add and remove keys/values to an arbitrary NSMutableDictionary that I initialized (not a part of the model).

The controller should be blind to this initialization pertinent to the model, but I can't seem to initialize the NSMutableDictionary properties by overriding the getters/setters of the model.  **What is the correct way in objective-C to set up my model with NSMutableDictionary properties such that I can set keys and values in it from my controller?**

I also feel like my many-dictionaries indexed by ids in an array solution is overkill.  If you can spot that and know the better way to deal with this in iOS, please feel free to lend your wisdom.

**EDIT**
At the request of Marcus Adams, here is the code where I use the NSMutableDictionary properties.  I do not initialize the NSMutableDictionary properties; where to do that so that it's appropriate to the MVC model is my question.  His answer has led me to try initializing by overriding "init", and this works as part of the instantiation of the model (Marcus Adams will be marked as the answer if he provides the explanation, since he led me to the answer, but answers with code samples for correctly overriding "init" will be up voted).

```
 // Now we're ready to store what's in the JSON.
    NSDictionary *stuff = jsonData[@"stuff"];
    NSMutableDictionary *tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSDictionary *thing in stuff) {
        [tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded setObject:thing[@"description"] forKey:thing[@"id"]]; // This works!

        theModel.thingDescriptions[thing[@"id"]] = thing[@"description"]; // This wasn't working!
        [theModel.thingIds addObject:thing[@"id"]]; // This is the array of ids used to retrieve values from each dictionary
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the JSON you are using is in fact valid?  Any time I am dealing with a problem related to JSON that is my first step.  You can test [here](http://jsonlint.com)

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it's valid.  I'm able to iterate through the JSON data.  I'm also able to set that JSON data to an intermediate NSMutableDictionary that I alloc-init outside of the model.  It's just the properties within the model that won't take in that valid, iterated JSON data.

Comment: Why not just store the dictionary you get back from parsing the JSON data as-is? You can pass `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` as an option.

Comment: @JimPuls, you might be on to that more natural solution intended for iOS.  The array listed in the question is nested within other JSON, though; does copying over the dictionary, as you say, allow me to iterate across the "stuff" array elements explicitly, without copying/iterating the other JSON elements around the array?

Comment: Let's see the code where create the NSMutableDictionaries.

Comment: You don't explain how you find stuff in step 3.  Do you iterate through your array of dictionaries and check each id field against the one you're looking for?

Comment: Code has been provided and the answer has been reached thanks to @MarcusAdams.

Comment: @HotLicks, the code now at the end of my question shows what you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your code should be working now. I was curious how you were copying the NSDictionaries and thought the problem might be there. Obviously, you discovered that you hadn't initialized tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded. I wouldn't use a getter to initialize unless you are keeping tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded around for awhile. If you are, storing it as a property and initializing it in a getter is the simplest thing to do.

```
// Getter ensures that when you reference self.tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded
/// it's always initialized
-(NSMutableDictionary *) tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded {
  if (!_tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded) {
    _tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  return _tempDictBecauseAllocNeeded;
}
```

Since the original JSON parsing, by default, creates mutable leaves, even though you assign it to an NSDictionary, each leaf in there is still mutable.

So, when you (shallow copy) over the leaves to your NSMutableDictionary, they are still mutable, of course.

Comment: Thanks!  This was the source of the problem, though I solved it by initializing the dictionary by overriding init in the model.  For future searchers: either of these will work for you, depending on how much or how little you want each abstraction to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

```
stuff = ( ...
```

This is not a JSON array, is it supposed to be? JSON array would be

```
stuff = [ ...
```

Comment: I copied/pasted from the output given in the console at the last line of my first bit of code that I included.  We also discussed the validity of the JSON in the comments: I am able to iterate through the JSON data as expected.

Comment: That's just the way NSLog prints an NSArray.